# Spring ClassCastException?

Tags: java, spring, h2

java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Double cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer (java.lang.Double and java.lang.Integer are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

```
//using lombok
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Quiz {
    @Id
    @Column
    int id;

    @Column
    String title;

    @Column
    String text;

    @ElementCollection
    @Column
    List<String> options;

    @ElementCollection
    @Column
    List<Integer> answer = new ArrayList<>(); //this is obviously a list of Integers
}
```

```
@Service
public class QuizService {
    @Autowired
    Repo repo;

    public List<Quiz> getAllQuiz(){
        List<Quiz> quizList = new ArrayList<>();
        repo.findAll().forEach(quiz -> quizList.add(quiz));
        return quizList;
    }

    public void saveNewQuiz(Quiz quiz){
        repo.save(quiz); //error occurred here
    }

    public void deleteQuiz(Quiz quiz){
        repo.delete(quiz);
    }
}
```

```
import engine.Quiz;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface Repo extends CrudRepository<Quiz, Integer> {
}
```

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/api/quizzes", produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public String newQuiz(@RequestBody String json){
        Import();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonObject jObj = new JsonObject();
        try {
            jObj = new JsonParser().parse(json).getAsJsonObject();
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        //test out the json
        requestHandler(jObj);

        Quiz quiz = new Quiz();
        int id = idGenerator();
        quiz.setId(id);
        quiz.setTitle(jObj.get("title").getAsString());
        quiz.setText(jObj.get("text").getAsString());
        quiz.setOptions(gson.fromJson(jObj.get("options").getAsJsonArray(), List.class));
        try {
            List<Integer> list = gson.fromJson(jObj.get("answer").getAsJsonArray(), List.class);
            quiz.setAnswer(list);
        }catch(Exception ignored) {}
        quizzes.add(quiz);
        service.saveNewQuiz(quiz); //error occured here

        return getQuiz(id);
    }
```

I never even touched Double, how could there be a class cast exception from Double to Integer?

Things I cannot do:

- I cannot change the type from Integer to Double because the project
  required Integers to function.
- I cannot change the database because the project requires h2 database

This exception perplexed me.

Comment: I'm sure you know what a debugger is .. have you tried to verify the incoming data? Have you verified the conversion of that data? Have you verified the data is passed down correctly to the repo?

Comment: @Tom The normal debugging process of printing out statements doesn't work with spring, I tried but nothing is printed out to the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved this problem;
First of all, instead of getting a List from json, I try to get a int[] instead, use that and convert to list